# Visual content of images are exactly same but pixels values are different

Tags: python, image-processing, camera, computer-vision, android-camera

I have taken 2 images one after another from the fixed camera without changing any environment conditions as well as without refocusing and the images look exactly the same to human eye. I have compared structural similarity which has a score of 0.74 and mean square error 330 instead of 1 and 0. I can think of that due to the burst , shutter or any other properties of the camera .

**Code i used.**

```
def compare_images(imageA, imageB,title,mulichanel=True):
    # compute the mean squared error and structural similarity
    # index for the images
    m = mse(imageA, imageB)
    s = measure.compare_ssim(imageA, imageB,multichannel=mulichanel)
    # setup the figure
    fig = plt.figure(title)
    plt.suptitle("MSE: %.2f, SSIM: %.2f" % (m, s))
    # show first image
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
    plt.imshow(imageA, cmap = plt.cm.gray)
    plt.axis("off")
    # show the second image
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)
    plt.imshow(imageB, cmap = plt.cm.gray)
    plt.axis("off")
    # show the images
    plt.show(
```

)

**Client Code:**

```
img_1 = cv2.imread('/path/to/image1')
img_2 = cv2.imread('path/to/image2')
img_1 = cv2.cvtColor(img_1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img_2 = cv2.cvtColor(img_2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
compare_images(img_2,img_1,"2 similer images")
```

**OutPut:**

[image]

In order to get to consecutive image with exact structure similarity (1) what
all the camera parameters need to control or any other way around

**Image Source**

Image 1 : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1chGP6Ia5ryRV1eRcg6iiCchcFlMg1k9F/view?usp=sharing

Image 2 : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gk6ibwI7hkU2frAFDyg4YD2-Pvl10u1B/view?usp=sharing

Best Regards,

Mohit

Comment: Sorry, but it is not clear what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about why SSIM is low, the fact is it is not the best measure for perceptual similarity. I understand that SSIM was created for a different purpose.

There is a research paper by NVIDIA proposing a new method addressing the issue:

https://research.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/node/3260/FLIP_Paper.pdf

Comment: Is there anyway i can take two pictures exactly same in terms of pixel if we have fixed camera as well as fixed object ?